# SignalR function return value

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I created a SignalR hub which contain the following hub function:

```
public bool GetStatus()
{
    return true;
}
```

I'm want to call this function from my JS code and get the request of this call. Something like this:

```
var result = hub.server.getStatus();
if (result)
    alert('success');
```

Is this possible without returning Task of bool?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by returning Task?

Comment: do you want it to return anything?

Comment: There is a option to return Task, which makes the whole process async. This what I'm want to avoid.

Comment: I don't think you HAVE to return anything. We use signalR and we don't return anything.  Maybe I don't understand the whole thing.

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  Hubs don't have return values, they make calls to clients.

Answer (score 27):

No. The SignalR JavaScript client is non-blocking; you will need to follow the Promise interface, like so:

```
hub.server.getStatus().done(function(result) { 
    if (result) {
        alert('success'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I note it isn't an _actual_ JavaScript `Promise<T>` but SignalR's own promise type (otherwise it would be called `then`, not `done`).

Comment: UPDATE: Ah, SignalR uses `JQueryPromise<T>` which is documented here: http://definitelytyped.org/docs/toastr--toastr/interfaces/jquerypromise.html

Answer (score 2):

On the client side you'll need to use the promise interface. but on the server side it's entirely up to you, the code below is from the SignalR guide [site](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubmethods):

Synchronous

```
public IEnumerable<Stock> GetAllStocks()
{
        // Returns data from memory.
        return _stockTicker.GetAllStocks();
}
```

Asynchronous

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Stock>> GetAllStocks()
{
    // Returns data from a web service.
    var uri = Util.getServiceUri("Stocks");
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Stock>>());
    }
}
```

Just change the server signature according to your needs